# Bitbucket pipeline fails when using custom php image

Tags: php, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I have created a custom Docker image, pushed it to dockerhub, added it to the bitbucket pipeline. It gets pulled but I cannot execute php. Note even `php -v` works, no output is visible. What am I doing wrong?

I have built the image in an intel processor. Also building the image on bitbucket and directly from there pushing it to dockerhub did not change anything.

This is the output I get...

[image]

The image is incuded in the pipeline as follows:

```
definitions:
  services:
    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.6.4
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'redacted'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'redacted'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'redacted'
  steps:
    - step: &TestPHP
        name: Test PHP
        image:
          name: "sensetence/hcwcrm-php80fpm:latest"
          username: $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME
          password: $DOCKERHUB_TOKEN
        deployment: test
        services:
          - mariadb
        script:
          - cd api
          - ls -lh
          - ls -lh /usr/local/bin
          - php -v
```

And this is how I am building the image (left out some software installation parts):

```
FROM php:8.0.25-fpm-alpine

ARG UID
ARG GID

ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# MacOS staff group's gid is 20, so is the dialout group in alpine linux. We're not using it, let's just remove it.
RUN delgroup dialout

RUN addgroup -g ${GID} --system symfony
RUN adduser -G symfony --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${UID} symfony

RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = symfony/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = symfony/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN echo "php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

[... here installation, copying files, setting up supercronic]
```

Comment: How have you defined the image in the pipeline.yml? If it is private repo have you logged in with your details?

Comment: What happens if you pull the image locally and run that same command? Can you share the relevant fragment of `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`? Is the image public? Have you tried downloading the logs?

Comment: @N1ngu When I run the image locally (intel CPU), it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. The Dockerfile also loads a php.ini, in this file are the following two lines to warm up opcache:

```
opcache.preload=/var/www/html/config/preload.php
opcache.preload_user=symfony
```

Looks like this path is not defined when the image is executed in the bitbucket? At least when the image is started and FPM wants to start running? I don't know, to be honest. I removed these two lines, everything worked.